# When there is the following entity, how should I write find where nestjs typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to use the typeorm to find the desired value in the technical -> mapping table <-item relationship.

However, the error "Unknown column 'tnItem.itemId' in 'where cause' occurs.

I know that an error occurs because it is an item rather than an itemId in tnItem, but I don't know how to write a query.

my entity

```
@Entity("tn_item")
export class TechnicianItem extends BaseModel {
    @ManyToOne(() => Technician, (technician) => technician.tnItem, {
        primary: true,
        lazy: true
    })
    @JoinColumn([{ name: "tn_id", referencedColumnName: "tnId" }])
    technician: Technician;

    @ManyToOne(() => Item, (item) => item.tnItem, {
        primary: true,
        lazy: true
    })
    @JoinColumn([{ name: "item_id", referencedColumnName: "itemId" }])
    item: Item;

    @Column("int", { nullable: false, name: "period" })
    period!: number;
}
```

my method

```js
    async findAllTechnician(searchDto: SearchDto): Promise<Technician[]> {
        const findTechnician = await this.find({
            relations: ["tnItem", "tnConcept"],
            where: (qb) => {
                qb.where(`tnItem.itemId IN (${searchDto.items})`).andWhere(
                    `tnConcept.conceptId IN (${searchDto.concepts})`
                );
            }
        });
        return findTechnician;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solved using the createQueryBuilder.

```
    async findAllTechnician(searchDto: SearchDto): Promise<Technician[]> {
        const findTechnician = await this.createQueryBuilder("tn")
            .innerJoinAndSelect(TechnicianItem, "tni", "tni.tnId = tn.tnId")
            .innerJoinAndSelect(TechnicianConcept, "tnc", "tnc.tnId = tn.tnId")
            .where("tni.itemId IN (:items)", { items: searchDto.items })
            .andWhere("tnc.conceptId IN (:concepts)", {
                concepts: searchDto.concepts
            })
            .getMany();
        return findTechnician;
    }
```